# Code coverage results do not match in local visual studio and TFS build server

Tags: visual-studio-2017, code-coverage, tfsbuild, vs-unit-testing-framework

recently i created unit test methods for my project solution. when i do code analysis to find out code coverage, it shows 82% code coverage.

But when i checked in my code on TFS, on build server code analysis report shows code coverage as 58%.

Please can someone let me know if they encountered this issue or any possible solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the TFS build definition, did you specify a **.runsetting** file or **Test Filter criteria** for code coverage analysis or just choose the "**CodeCoverageEnabled**" setting?

If you set the filter or .runsettings, that should be the reason why the code coverage results are different. Please see below articles for details.

- [Configure unit tests by using a .runsettings file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file)
- [Customizing Code Coverage Analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/customizing-code-coverage-analysis)

So, If you want to do a comparison, you should be under the same conditions. The filter will exclude those test methods which do not meet the criteria. So not all tests are run, and the code coverage result is not same with developers.

You could delete the filter criteria and test again.

More other reasons to cause the difference please see :[Troubleshooting Code Coverage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/troubleshooting-code-coverage)

[image]